# Issues when trying to space XMLHttpRequest() API calls every 5 seconds with setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am working on the initial data pull for a project. It will be cached and further requests will be much less.  I am attempting to space out my API requests every 5 seconds to avoid overloading the server and hitting the rate limit per their rules.  It does not seem that my `setTimeout()` function is actually working as desired. I logged time stamps to see and all iterations seem to be happening at the exact same time.  I think this somehow due to the asynchronous nature of javascript, but I'm not sure how to remedy it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Code Excerpt:**

```
var leagues;
function getLeagues(){

    var reqURL = "url";
    var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
    data.open("GET", reqURL);
    data.responseType = "text";
    data.send();

    // parse data on load
    data.onload = function() {
        // League IDs
        leagues = JSON.parse(data.response)

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            delay(i); // iterate every 5 secs
        }
    };
}

function delay(i) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d.getSeconds())
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using `i` somehow?, like `5000 * i` instead of just `5000`?

Comment: This is not an efficient way you are doing but still you can achieve here by making the 5000 to `i*5000`

Comment: @dandavis sorry it wasn’t clear. This is specifically setup to debug why it wasn’t spacing. In the actual code the leagues array have ~2000 objects that are iterated over and i is used to make further api calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` is a browser API that will guarantees not an exact delay time to execute after but a minimum time to execute a function so it's not related to `js`.

`setTimeout` cause the browser to set a timer after x milliseconds, when finished the function you pass will be in the event queue, but it won't necessarily execute, if event queue was completely empty, you are lucky and the function get executed immediately after 5 seconds, otherwise the function have to wait in queue until each function get executed before so we have (5 seconds + some times until the function get in the head of the queue then get executed).

calling `setTimeout` five times in sequence (using a `for` loop) with the same time delay will add the same function 5 consequent times in the event queue, all will be executed at the same time because of the same time delay used for all of them. so a solution would be to use different delay time for each function.

---

I'll suggest the solution for the same problem, because I faced it alot

Callback based solution

```js
repeat(processingRequest, 5, 5000);


function processingRequest(){
  console.log('Making request at', new Date().getTime());
}


function repeat(func, howManyTimes, milliSecondsInterval){

  if(howManyTimes > 0)
    delay(() => {
      func();
      howManyTimes--;
      repeat(func, howManyTimes, milliSecondsInterval);
    }, milliSecondsInterval);
}

function delay(func, milliSeconds){
  setTimeout(func, milliSeconds);
}
```

---

Promise based solution(more preferred)

```js
repeat(processingRequest, 5, 5000);


function processingRequest(){
  console.log('Making request at', new Date().getTime());
}

function repeat(func, howManyTimes, milliSeconds){
  delay(milliSeconds)
  .then(() => {

    func();
    howManyTimes--;

    if(howManyTimes > 0)
      repeat(func, howManyTimes, milliSeconds);
  });
}

function delay(milliSeconds){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve();
    }, milliSeconds);
  });
}
```

---

using a library like rxjs(providing a `repeat` and `delay`) will make things even more simple

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/repeat

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/delay

even though not every application need rxjs, but we have to say it give the programmer a great power over clean sync or async operations

---

[References]

For further knowledge about Browser API & Event queue

Cool talk from Philip Roberts

https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ?t=1165

from THE BEST great `js` resource I've found

https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/async%20%26%20performance/ch1.md

Answer (score 2):

You call `delay` to tell JS to do something in 5 seconds.

Then you **immediately** call `delay` to tell JS to do something in 5 seconds again.

So 5 seconds later the first `delay` timeout triggers, then immediately after that the second one triggers.

---

If you want to space them apart then you need to either:

- Call delay the second time in the function that setTimeout calls so the second timer doesn't start under the first one is finished
- Multiply your times so the first one is 5 seconds but the second is 10 seconds and so on
- Refactor the code to use `setInterval` instead

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize that `setTimeout` didnt block execution.  doing 5000*i with the original code works without refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead of a timeout. The `setTimeout` function will wait five seconds and all code will be executed, because it does not block the execution. A promise instead will do that:

```
async function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
};
```

You can use the promise inside of an async loop:

```
  async function getLeagues(){
        var reqURL = "url";
        var data = new XMLHttpRequest();
        data.open("GET", reqURL);
    data.responseType = "text";
    data.send();

    // parse data on load
    data.onload = function() {
        // League IDs
        leagues = JSON.parse(data.response)
        const delays = [...new Array(5)]; // To have something to loop over

         for await (const d of delays) {
             await delay(5000);
          }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function delay(i) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log(d.getSeconds())
  }, i * 5000);
}
```

The process of setting up the timeout i.e. the calls to setTimeout() — takes almost no time at all. If a succession of timeout requests is made, the delay value is the same for each one, then once that amount of time has elapsed.. all the timer handlers will be called consecutively rapidly. If you need the handlers to be called at intervals, you can either use setInterval(), which is called exactly like setTimeout() but will fire more than once after repeated delays of 5000, or instead, you can establish the timeouts and multiply the time value by your iteration counter i.e. 'i' in this case. The value of i is multiplied by the original delay value, so calling that 5 times in a loop will result in delays of 5 seconds, 10 seconds, 15 seconds, 20 seconds, and 25 seconds.